# Django debug toolbar wrong paths

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I have created a Django app and just deployed it to a server. I use some extra django features such as the django-debug-toolbar which was installed from my requirements.txt file using `pip`.

When I run my app locally, on localhost, everything works fine and the extra features are loaded successfully.

Here is the right structure of the sources loaded:

[image]

But when I run my app from the server for some reason the paths are not correct.

[image]

And in my browser's console I get these errors:

[image]

All these paths are from the installed packages like the django-debug-toolbar and it wouldn't make sense to change them. For example, the `toolbar.js` file is loaded with this command:
`<script src="{% static 'debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js' %}"></script>`

which can be found in the:
`lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/templates/debug_toolbar/base.html`
 file, which was created after I installed all the packages from my requirements.txt file.

That should work fine. It does work fine when I run it locally, but it doesn't when I run on the new server. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ran `collectstatic`? you should also try to post textual information as *text* instead of images

Comment: Is it necessary to run `collectstatic`? I have copied the settings for `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and as I said it works fine when I run locally. Also, what textual information would you need for this issue?

Comment: It works locally because the static folder is the same, so yes `collectstatic` is probably needed. the textual information I refer to is your (relevant) console output

Comment: @Sayse Thanks for your help! I ran `collectstatic` and I also made some changes on the paths as the `STATIC_ROOT` directory was not the same with the one set in the nginx conf file. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to call `collectstatic` when you make changes to the static files.

What this command does is copy the static files from their `static` folders to the location that you specify in your `STATIC_ROOT` directory, this should be the same as where nginx is looking for files.

The error you received is because those files weren't in the directory your nginx was looking in.